# A way to create command line program with Air 2?

Tags: actionscript-3, air

Is there any way to create an Air 2 program that runs just in the command line? (no windows, no gui, etc)

Something similar to Windows Ping program. It would accept arguments and then output std out.

Answer (score 1):

No, AIR is not really meant for creating command-line applications - it's just not the right tool for the job.

You would be better off looking at implementing your application in Java, C#/VB.NET, Python or Groovy (and innumerable other more suitable languages).

If you really have your heart set on Actionscript/Javascript-style syntax then you should look into [Haxe](http://haxe.org/).

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check out [CommandProxy](http://www.mikechambers.com/blog/2008/01/17/commandproxy-net-air-integration-proof-of-concept/) as a possible solution.

Comment: Which part of CommandProxy should I be looking at? As far as I can tell, AIR 2 beta antiquates CommandProxy.